# .bashrc - command-based environment variable not being set on new terminal window

Tags: bash, macos

In my ~/.bashrc file, I'd like to set an environment variable that itself is the result of running a command:

```
export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=`which chromium`
```

If I open a new terminal window and run `env`, I do see this environment variable, but it has been set to an empty string:

```
PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=
```

If I then run `source ~/.bashrc` and check `env` again, I see this value set as I'd expect:

```
PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin/chromium
```

Why is it that the results of this command don't seem to be used to set that environment variable the first time this file is executed when I open a new terminal window? Other non-command-based variables I define in the file are correctly set in new terminals, so I have to assume that it's something in the way I've written the command. Is there a more reliable way to set this so that I don't have to re-run `source ~/.bashrc` on every terminal window?

This is on MacOS, Ventura 13.2.1. For reference, here are the contents of ~/.bash_profile and ~/.bashrc, respectively:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc" ]] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"
[[ -s "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ]] && source "$HOME/.bash_aliases"

# Adds brew to PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

# Adds asdf & asdf completions to PATH
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash
```

```
export BASH_SILENCE_DEPRECATION_WARNING=1

# Resolves Puppeteer M1 Mac issue by following the instructions in chetbox's comments at https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/6622
# and making sure to include the --no-quarantine flag when installing Chromium via Homebrew -
# https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/112986
export PUPPETEER_SKIP_CHROMIUM_DOWNLOAD=true
export PUPPETEER_EXECUTABLE_PATH=`which chromium`
```

Comment: Make sure you execute that command after updating `$PATH` to include the directory containing `chromium`. That might be done by the `eval` command, which is after sourcing `.bashrc`.

Comment: @Barmar thank you, I rearranged the `~/.bash_profile` and put the `eval` before sourcing the other files and that fixed the problem. If you want to answer this question with that solution, I'd most definitely accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the command that updates `$PATH` before calling `which`, so it will find the executable.

```
# Adds brew to PATH
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

[[ -s "$HOME/.bashrc" ]] && source "$HOME/.bashrc"
[[ -s "$HOME/.bash_aliases" ]] && source "$HOME/.bash_aliases"

# Adds asdf & asdf completions to PATH
. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh
. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash
```

Comment: Mind, it'd be better to replace `which` with something more efficient (like `command -v`) while we're in there.

Comment: Yes, that's a separate issue.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy that seems to work, too, but could you explain why that'd be more efficient? Thank you.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then

Comment: @skwidbreth, to summarize _very_ briefly (though that full link is worth reading) -- excluding shells which offer it as an extension (a set bash isn't part of), `which` isn't built into the shell -- it's an external executable, like `/bin/ls`, so all the normal machinery that needs to run to launch things that (well) _aren't built into the shell_ is invoked in using it. (Also, `which` isn't POSIX-mandatory, so operating systems can choose not to provide it at all).

Comment: Many thanks to both of you for helping me to fix my problem and learn me something new.